# Strange behavior with UNIX `basename` command

Tags: macos, bash, unix, shell

I want to use `basename` to get the basenames for a newline-delimited list of file paths. It seems to work when n > 2:

```
$ basename `echo -e '/foo/bar \n /food/baz \n /oof/rab'`
bar
baz
rab
```

However, when n = 2, it only outputs the first line.

```
$ basename `echo -e '/foo/bar \n /food/baz'`
bar
```

Why didn't it print `baz`? Is this a bug in `basename`? Here is my platform info:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin MacBook-Pro-4.local 15.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Sun Jun  4 21:43:07 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3248.70.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`basename` does not take a list of paths (let alone one delimited by newlines), it takes *a single* path (optionally followed by a suffix to remove).

Additionally, when you use command (like `echo`) in backticks, the shell takes that command's output, splits it into "words" separated by whitespace (generally spaces, tabs, and newlines, but you can change it with `$IFS`), expands any wildcards it finds, and passes the result of all that to the other command (`basename` in this case). As a result, the newlines in the `echo` output are treated as just more whitespace between words, not passed to `basename` at all. So this command:

```
basename `echo -e '/foo/bar \n /food/baz \n /oof/rab'`
```

is equivalent to:

```
basename "/foo/bar" "/food/baz" "/oof/rab"
```

...and apparently when `basename` gets three arguments like this, it prints the base name of each argument separately. The man page for `basename` doesn't document this behavior, so if anything it's a bug that it doesn't give an error in this case.

Similarly, this command:

```
basename `echo -e '/foo/bar \n /food/baz'`
```

is equivalent to

```
basename "/foo/bar" "/food/baz"
```

...but in this case `basename`'s behavior is defined and is quite different -- it takes the base name of the first argument, removes the second argument from its end (if it matches), and prints the result. "bar" doesn't end with "/food/baz", so it just prints "bar".

Also, `echo -e` is weirdly nonportable (even between different versions of OS X!). Below, I've used bash's `$' '` string format to get escape sequences translated.

If you want to print the base names of a newline-separated list of paths, use a loop to run `basename` on each separately:

```
while read -r filepath; do
    basename "$filepath"
done <<< $'/foo/bar \n /food/baz'
```

Or just use `sed` to delete up to the first "/" in each line:

```
echo $'/foo/bar \n /food/baz \n /oof/rab' | sed 's@^.*/@@'
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using `xargs -n 1` instead of a loop.

Answer (score 2):

basename has an optional argument **suffix**
e.g.

```
basename include/stdio.h .h
```

returns `"stdio"`

You second argument `"/food/baz"` delimited by white spaces `" \n "` was considered as the suffix. As it's not matched, it returns `"bar"` only.

You can try

```
basename `echo -e '/foo/bar \n r'`
```

which should return `"ba"`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about OS revs, but there might be some different basename utilties.  Mine (/usr/bin/basename on Mac OS 10.12.6) give an error about that "-e" in the echo sub-command, but that might be my shell (tcsh).

This works for me:

```
basename /foo/bar /food/baz /oof/rab
```

Answer (score 0):

to complement @Gordon's answer, `basename` (and its friend `dirname`)  is sometime use to remove suffixes.

```
$ basename /foo/bar.c .c
bar
```

this can be handy when compiling or processing file. e.g :

```
SRC=$1
DEST=$(dirname $SRC)/$(basename $SRC .txt).csv

process ${SRC} > ${DEST}
```

(note that above snippet will not work with file with funny char (space,tab or newline)